# Can't use .bashrc file on remote server from ssh within emacs

Tags: spacemacs, emacsclient, terminal-emacs

Login to remote server with ssh in Emacs, general commands run well. Such as `ls`, `docker ls`, etc.

```
C-x C-f /ssh:...
```

But when I tried to run a command which alias to another which set in the .bashrc file. It doesn't work.

When I check `cat ~/.bashrc`, it returned the content of local .bashrc. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tramp, the package handling remote files, does not load `.profile` or `.bashrc` or alike.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very right answer.